# How do I apply a =COUNT function while filtering for a specific word within texts?

Tags: function, google-sheets

Okay so I've been trying to figure this out for a while and thought I might as well just ask the internet. I have a Google Sheet with analyses from a Google Form. This is one we use year in year out, and at the end of the year we check all the numbers and do an analysis and such. So to do so, we have to filter per year to get only the numbers of said year. We have a quick overview page that tells us how many forms have been filled per year, but I have been unable to make it work automatically.
Currently we use the =COUNT function, navigate to the general form reactions tab and select the items of a certain year. My colleagues aren't that well versed with computers though, so they have been having some trouble (even though this isn't that difficult and I have a note in the tab explaining what to do), and I wanted to make it easier for them and update automatically, so that if a new form gets filled out, the count gets updated as well.
So is there any way I can do a =COUNT with a filter?

I've tried the =COUNTIF and add the year "2023", but it doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty sure it is because the format of the dates are: "28-3-2023 13:59:11", so the year will only be one part of the full text, if that makes any sense. Anyone have a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well since the dates are in dates format, you can try to do `=COUNTIF(C3,">="&DATE(2023,1,1))`

We create a new date to compare!

LMK if you have questions.

Comment: Well I tried this and variations of it. Applied to my sheet it would make something like this: =COUNTIF('Formulierreacties 1'!A2:A198 ; ">="&DATE(1-1-2023))
But then I get a result of 0, which should be 16. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The date function is used as `DATE(year, month, day)`.
You have used it as `DATE(day, month, year)`.
`=COUNTIF('Formulierreacties 1'!A2:A198 ; ">="&DATE(2023-1-1))`

Comment: Ah dates in our sheet are formatted as day,month,year ("28-3-2023 13:59:11") but yes, I also tried this and same problem unfortunately

Comment: Wait I just noticed you used a semicolon.

Please use this formula: `=COUNTIF('Formulierreacties 1'!A2:A198 , ">="&DATE(2023-1-1))`

Comment: Also please change your dates from strings to actual dates.

`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A2, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))`

Comment: That last formula didn't change it into an actual date but into a number (eg. 44197), but I managed with a =TO_DATE function. Unfortunately still a result of 0... I feel like I've tried everything and the program is just set against me. In my head the solution could be so simple! 
Oh and as soon as I change the semicolon to a comma, I get a parse error. Changing it back to the semicolon gives me the 0 as result again. I think my colleagues changed it in the settings as it makes it more similar to Excel. Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: No worries. As far as my knowledge goes the code I provided should've worked. Im sorry it didnt :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay adding the answer myself in case anyone is interested as the problem was mostly the format, which I was able to fix quite easily. I first changed the format of the whole dates column from "date time" to just "date" and after changed it to "plain text". This left me with just the date (day/month/year). Then applied a simple `=COUNTIF(range ; "*"&field with text/year I wanted counted&"*")` so for me applied this made `=COUNTIF('Formulierreacties 1'!A:A ; "*"&A3&"*")`. One could also change the condition to `"*YEAR*"` but in my case referring to a certain cell was easier to just drag out to apply in the future. Change to comma if that's the format your Google Sheets use instead of a semicolon.